# How can I access memcache on Heroku via command line

Tags: heroku, memcached

How can I access memcache on Heroku via command, I just want to look up some key and delete it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using some gem to handle it, such as Dalli?

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku run console --app your-app-name
```

for Cedar, or

```
heroku console --app your-app-name
```

for Bamboo and Aspen.  Then

```
m = Memcached.new
```